# JWT token and Owin authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin, jwt

I have MVC front end application using WebApi 2 application for authentication and authorization.  I am using JWT tokens for the same.  So far I have been able to successfully authenticate and receive back a token… I can further access the restricted resource ([Authorize] attribute) by adding an Authorization token to the header using POSTMAN tool.

```
Authorization: “Bearer <jwt.token.string>”
```

Issue is, I am not able to intercept the call in MVC pipeline to add the token to the httpHeader.  It always routes me back to the login page.  Not the case when I use the POSTMAN tool.  I have unsuccessfully tried injecting the token at following points:

- Extending Authorize attribute with custom implementation
- Adding a custom ActionFilterAttribute
- Adding custom DelegatingHandler
- Owin pipeline using StageMarker (PipelineStageAuthenticate) in Startup.cs

In all above cases I am hitting the event because I can debug.  I have strong suspicion that I am hitting the authorization point before I set my header but I can’t figure out sequence of flow to properly intercept the HttpContext object and inject the Authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

After successful authentication, add

```
var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
            var authenticateResult = await ctx.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);
            ctx.Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);
            var applicationCookieIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(authenticateResult.Identity.Claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            ctx.Authentication.SignIn(applicationCookieIdentity);
```

This will create a signed cookie and your Authorize attribute will automatically read the cookie. All your requests will become authorized subsequently.